# How to change icon in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#MY Code
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700")
root.title("MY_OS LOGIN/REGISTER")
icon=PhotoImage("C:\\Users\\Malay\\Desktop\\Main\\malay\\Python Scripts\\My OS GUI\\favicon.ico")
root.iconphoto(True,icon)
```

#Error I'm facing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Malay\Desktop\Main\malay\Python Scripts\My OS GUI\main.py", line 35, in 
root.iconphoto(True,icon)
File "C:\Users\Malay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 2125, in wm_iconphoto
self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, "-default", *args)
tkinter.TclError: failed to create color bitmap for "C:\Users\Malay\Desktop\Main\malay\Python Scripts\My OS GUI\favicon.ico"`enter code here`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the window icon in a tkinter application:

Add this piece of code

```
root.iconbitmap("yourimage.ico")
```

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be two reasons this is not working. First PhotoImage does not work with the .ico file type. Second, the file name is a keyword argument, so your code should look like this.

```
#MY Code
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1200x700")
root.title("MY_OS LOGIN/REGISTER")
# Comment out incorrect file type
# icon=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Malay\\Desktop\\Main\\malay\\Python Scripts\\My OS GUI\\favicon.ico")
# Using keyword file and using a png
icon=PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Malay\\Desktop\\Main\\malay\\Python Scripts\\My OS GUI\\favicon.png")
root.iconphoto(True,icon)
```